# Java Midi Sequencer doesn't play after recording

Tags: java, midi

I've written a little midi recorder, which is supposed to play the track afterwards:

```
Sequencer seqr=MidiSystem.getSequencer();

//Transmitters and receivers here

seqr.startRecording();

//Some Stuff (basically waiting)

seqr.stopRecording();
seqr.setTickPosition(0);
seqr.setLoopStartPoint(0);
seqr.setLoopEndPoint(seqr.getTickLength());
seqr.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
seqr.start();
```

It doesnt, but - and that confuses me - works fine if I add:

```
File midFile=new File("MyMidiFile.mid");
MidiSystem.write(seqr.getSequence(), 1, midFile);
seqr.setSequence(MidiSystem.getSequence(midFile));
```

after the `stopRecoding()` it plays,

which shows me, that the recording and playing works fine.

**//End of Problem**

**Edit**

My whole midi code as requested

Transmitters and receivers

```
public static MidiDevice inputDevice;
public static MidiDevice outputDevice;
public static Transmitter usbTransmitter;
public static Receiver usbReciever;

public static Sequencer seqr;
public static Transmitter seqTransmitter;
public static Receiver seqReciever;
```

Initialization:

```
try{
    seqr = MidiSystem.getSequencer();

    Info[] midiDeviceInfo = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();

    inputDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(midiDeviceInfo[1]);
    outputDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(midiDeviceInfo[4]);
    seqr = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    inputDevice.open();
    outputDevice.open();
    seqr.open();

    seqReciever = seqr.getReceiver();
    seqTransmitter = seqr.getTransmitters().get(0);

    usbTransmitter = inputDevice.getTransmitter();
    usbReciever = outputDevice.getReceiver();
    usbTransmitter.setReceiver(seqReciever);
    seqTransmitter.setReceiver(usbReciever);

    Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 24);

    seqr.setSequence(seq);
    seqr.setTickPosition(0);
} catch (MidiUnavailableException | InvalidMidiDataException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Recording:

```
Track track;
Sequencer seqr;
Sequence seq;

public TrackControler(Sequencer seqr) {
    this.seqr = seqr;
    this.seq = seqr.getSequence();
    this.track = seq.createTrack();
}

private void startRecordNow() {
    seqr.recordEnable(track, -1);
    seqr.startRecording();
}

private void endRecordNow() {
    seqr.stopRecording();

    seqr.setTickPosition(0);
    seqr.setLoopStartPoint(0);
    seqr.setLoopEndPoint(seqr.getTickLength());
    seqr.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    seqr.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your MIDI recording or playing code, I would have to guess that `MidiSystem.write()` or `Sequencer.setSequence()` is doing some initialization that you are overlooking. My second guess is that `Sequencer.stopRecording()` is not leaving things in the right state to be played.

That's the best I can do without further information.

**Update (so you don't have to look through the comments):**

It seems Java does some caching, and one needs something like `seqr.setSequence(seqr.getSequence()` to commit the caches. I've looked for a more direct way to do this, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Thats the midi part of my code. Does this give you any clue?

Comment: Have you tried `seqr.recordingDisable(track);` when you stop recording? Also, I would add a debug check for the length of the Sequence (`seq. getMicrosecondLength()` will do) just to make sure something recorded.

Comment: I didnt know about the disable, but it doesn't fix my problems. I have `System.out.println(track.size() - 1 + " events");` in my code and some other debug prints. So I can tell you for sure that the tracks aren't empty

Comment: If read through the `RealTimeSequnecer` source code. The `setSequence()` does some cache refreshing, which is also called if I do `seqr.setSequence(seqr.getSequence());` and it magically works...

Comment: What happens if you insert `seqr.setSequence(seqr.getSequence());` instead of the statements writing a file and reading it back? I know it shouldn't make sense, but I'm guessing there's something going on when the sequence is set, and if it works, at least you have a workaround that doesn't involve writing a file. ;-)